# apply search filter for two lists GenericAPIView

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a view which return 3 lists (restaurants-meal-offers)
I want to apply search filter on the name field on all of them how can I achieve this

```
class SearchResult(generics.GenericAPIView):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,filters.SearchFilter]
    filter_fields = ("name",)
    search_fields = ("name",)

    def get(self,request):
       rests= models.Restaurant.objects.filter()
       rests_serializer = serializers.RestaurantDisplaySerializer(rests, many=True)
       meals= models.Meal.objects.filter(res_id__in=list(rests))
       meals_serializer = serializers.MealSerializer(meals,many=True)
       offers = models.Offer.objects.filter(res_id__in= list(rests))
       offers_serializer = serializers.OffersSerializer(offers,many=True)
      Response({"meals":meals_serializer.data,"restaurants":rests_serializer.data,"offers":offers_serializer.data},
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather, I would recommend you to build a nested serializer like this -

```
class RestaurantDisplaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    meals = MealSerializer()
    offers = OffersSerializer()
    
    class Meta:
        model = models.Restaurant
        fields = '__all__'
```

In your views, instead of `filter_fields` use `filterset_class` -

```
class SearchResult(generics.GenericAPIView):

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,filters.SearchFilter]

    filterset_class = CustomFilterClass

    def get(self,request):

       return models.Restaurant.objects.filter()
```

You can create your own custom filters to make it work on nested objects. Refer to the DRF documentation [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).